# Laravel's 5.2.33 Analogue (Data Mapper) orm Query Exception

Tags: php, postgresql, laravel, laravel-5, datamapper

I'm getting

> Undefined column: 7 ERROR: no existe la columna «users_id_seq»
>   LINE 1: ...ated_at", "updated_at") values ($1, $2) returning "users_id_...
>   ^ (SQL: insert into "users" ("created_at", "updated_at") values (2016-05-26 15:19:02, 2016-05-26 15:19:02) returning "users_id_seq")

When running an insert from a controller

this is my entity class

```
namespace App\Entities\Users;
use Analogue\ORM\Entity;

class BaseEntity extends Entity
{
    private $remember_token;
    private $created_at;
    private $updated_at;
    private $deleted_at;
    private $id;
    private $name;
    private $email;
    private $password;
    private $identification;
    private $cellphone;

    Here are getter/setter pairs for each property

}
```

And this is my map class

```
namespace App\Entities\Users;

use App\Entities\BaseEntityMap;

class UserMap extends BaseEntityMap
{
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    public $softDeletes = true;
    public $timestamps = true;
}
```

And this is the controller class

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Users;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Http\ServiceResponse;
use App\Entities\Users\User;
use Faker\Factory as Faker;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Monolog\Logger as Log;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function createRandom()
    {
        $logger = new Log("error");
        $randomUsers = array();
        for($i=0; $i<1000; $i++)
        {
            $userMapper = $this->mapper->mapper(User::class);
            $faker = Faker::create();
            $user = new User();
            $user->setName($faker->name);
            $user->setEmail($faker->email);
            $user->setPassword(bcrypt(rand(1000, 9999)));
            $user->setIdentification(bcrypt(rand(1000000, 100000000)));
            $user->setCellphone($faker->phoneNumber);
            //$user->setCreatedAt(Carbon::now());
            //$user->setUpdatedAt(Carbon::now());
            //$user->setDeletedAt(null);
            $logger->error("user --> " . print_r($user, true));
            $userMapper->store($user);
            $randomUsers[] = $user->convertToStdClass();
        }
        $response = new ServiceResponse(0, "createRandom", $randomUsers, "success");
        return response()->json($response->toJson());
    }
}
```

And this is what the query looks like on the postgres log file

```
2016-05-26 10:22:17 COT [4777-1] postgres@ewbackend ERROR:  no existe     la columna «users_id_seq» en carácter 76
2016-05-26 10:22:17 COT [4777-2] postgres@ewbackend SENTENCIA:  insert    into "users" ("created_at", "updated_at") values ($1, $2) returning   "users_id_seq"
```

In english it's says that the column "users_id_seq" doesn't exists, but I already check on the db, and that sequence exists.

And this is the sql for the user table

```
-- Table: public.users

-- DROP TABLE public.users;

CREATE TABLE public.users
(
    id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('users_id_seq'::regclass),
    name character varying(255) NOT NULL,
    email character varying(255) NOT NULL,
    password character varying(255) NOT NULL,
    identification character varying(255) NOT NULL,
    cellphone character varying(255) NOT NULL,
    remember_token character varying(100),
    created_at timestamp(0) without time zone,
    updated_at timestamp(0) without time zone,
    deleted_at timestamp(0) without time zone,
    CONSTRAINT users_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT users_email_unique UNIQUE (email),
    CONSTRAINT users_identification_unique UNIQUE (identification) 
 )
 WITH (
 OIDS=FALSE
);
 ALTER TABLE public.users
 OWNER TO postgres;
```

I also check the table (I created with a migration, just add some fields to the migration user example included with laravel 5.2.33) and all columns are there, with the correct types

I try assigning the dates by my self, but that make no difference.

I also try to quit the timestamps=true on my map class but then i see another error in which the query has no fields or values on the postgres log file, and I need the timestamps columns.

The log showings the user instance, shows that all of the data was set correctly.

I also try to put the entity properties public instead of private but that doesn't work.

So I apreciate any ideas on this issue. Also if can you tell me if analogue support postgres transactions (a set of queries that runs as one in order to fail if one of the queries fails or commit only if all the queries were successfull operations )

Comment: Can you include the SQL definition of your `users` table?

Comment: I will edit the question to include that, one minute please

Comment: I put the sql on the question, too thank you

Answer (score 0):

Analogue Entities use magic setters getters, so you don't have to manually add private properties + getters and setters.

Did you try :

class BaseEntity extends Entity
{

}

And set your column like this :

`$user->name($faker->name);
$user->email($faker->email);
etc..`

And yes afaik, it does support transactions on Postgres.

Comment: Hi, I see, but the management told me that i was taking too much time on the data mapper so now we are using the native active record. But thank you for the reply, i will try at home just for the heck of it